# Oracle Trigger fails after several times it is triggerd

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have two triggers. One trigger for UPDATE and INSERT and one trigger for DELETE.

```
create or replace
TRIGGER insup_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON USER_GROUPS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PROJECTS 
    SET TOUCHED = 1 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT PJ_ID 
             FROM PROJECT_ROLES_GROUPS 
             WHERE GRP_ID = :NEW.GRP_ID);
END;
```

and the trigger for delete:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER MARK
BEFORE DELETE  ON USER_GROUPS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE PROJECTS 
    SET TOUCHED = 1 
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT PJ_ID 
             FROM PROJECT_ROLES_GROUPS 
             WHERE GRP_ID = :OLD.GRP_ID);
END;
```

Now these triggers work fine a few times but after that the errors are thrown

```
  ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation
  ORA-06512: at "MARK", line 3
  ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MARK'
```

Triggering the triggers from SQL Developer by doing manual insert and delete does not trigger the error, this error appears from an .net applications that does the inserts and deletes.

Am I missing something ?

EDIT:

Reading the comments I got the hint that the problem might be in the vb.net code. I had:

```
adTrans = ADOCon.BeginTransaction()
adCMD = New OdbcCommand(vsSQL, ADOCon)
adCMD.Transaction = adTrans

        Try
            adCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
            adTrans.Commit() <- here is the error it should be
            -> adCMD.Transaction.Commit()
        Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Try to rollback the transaction
            Try
                adTrans.Rollback()
                If vbSuppressOutput = False Then
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End If

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
            Catch
                ' Do nothing here; transaction is not active.
            End Try
            Return False
        End Try
```

So I tried with the modified code and I cannot reproduce the problem anymore.
Thank you very very very much for your spot on comments!

Comment: usually, ora-01013 is an indication of a timeout. Are these long operations?

Comment: @OldProgrammer just an insert of a row with 2 columns, lightning fast, but indeed the ExecuteNonQuery function from vb.net takes a lot of times when it gives this error

Comment: Any chance that you have a problem where multiple sessions are trying to update the same row without committing, one session is blocking, and the application is set to time out after a period of time?  That seems consistent with what you're describing but we'd need to look at wait events and such to see whether that's really what's going on.

Comment: It is not part of a larger transaction?  Tale a look at setting the timeout to a larger [value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If that fixes the problem, then you have some issue with your vb.net client.

Comment: @JustinCave your comment lead me to the error. Thank you very much.
also 
OldProgrammer your comment too lead me to the error. Thank you very much!

Comment: You might consider only updating the project table for rows where touched does not already equal 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edit of the question is wrong.

As the comments suggested the problem was that I did not commit the transactions done with SQL Developer.

Because of that the transactions done with the VB.net application were unable to complete and the errors were generated.